# Disable "next" button when no more data available

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a bar graph with `d3.js` that has in some cases hundreds of entries, so in order for it to remain readable I've created "previous 10" and "next 10" buttons.  I was able to disable the "previous 10" button from loading non-existing data by creating variable `c` which gets `+1` or `-1` added to it when you click either the next or previous buttons, and when it hits `0` it disables.  However, the "next 10" button is different, because each set of data has a different amount of rows (bars).  Is there any way I can disable the button when it hits the end of the `csv` file?

Here's what I tried doing, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
   <button type="button" id="bt1" class="bt1">Previous 10</button>
   <button type="button" id="bt2" class="bt2">Next 10</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
            d3.select("#bt2").on("click", () =>{
                a += 10;
                b += 10;
                c += 1;
                update(a,b,c);
                });

            d3.select("#bt1").on("click", () => {
                a -= 10;
                b -= 10;
                c -= 1;
                update(a,b,c);
                });

var counts = {};
   data.forEach(function(r) {
   if (!counts[r.Charge]) {
   counts[r.Charge] = 0; }
   counts[r.Charge]++;
});

if (c === 1) { d3.select("#bt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }   
else { document.getElementById("bt1").removeAttribute('disabled'); }

if ( counts === "0") { d3.select("#bt2").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }   
else { document.getElementById("bt2").removeAttribute('disabled'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure without the whole code (JSFiddle would be very useful if you can create it), but in the last if statement you are === comparing object counts with "0". I believe this will be true, since counts is an object. Are you sure you didn't mean to do: `counts[some_value] === 0` (or, if you want to check if Object counts is empty - `Object.keys(counts).length === 0`?